# Question about hashing passwords and program turning off and on

Tags: python, hash

Do I want to hash the password and the hash into a database? If so, I got a question about how to get the same hash if my program turns off? When I rerun my program, I'm getting a different hash for two same passwords. I won't be able to see if the hash for password is the same for the hash stored in a database.

Comment: What hashing function are you using. Cryptographic hashing should produce exactly the same result for the same input.

Comment: I'm using sha256 and pbkdf2

Comment: Are you using a random salt? If so, you need to store the salt alongside the password in order to check the password.

Comment: Yes, what @nneonneo said. Just test by running sha256 only and see that repeated hashing should produce the same result.

Comment: using just sha256 seem to produce the same hash, I guess the way I was doing doesn't work